# Having problems putting button over webview

Tags: java, android, pointers, null

I'm trying to place a button over a webview, and I found the easiest way to do it is through xml. 
My MainActivity onCreate looks as such:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button buttonClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);

        mWebview  = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enables javascript


        System.out.println("Loading Webpage...");
        new tts().execute("");
        mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.aljazeera.com/news/americas/2013/07/20137113200544375.html");
        mWebview.addView(buttonClick);
        setContentView(mWebview);

    }
```

My xml looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView 
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Pause" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For some reason I'm getting a fatal error with a null pointer exception. Anyone have any insight as to why this is happening?

Comment: Well if you paste the LogCat output maybe the error might become visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); // this should come before initialization
...//rest of the code
}
```

You can `findViewById` current view hierarchy set to the activity. You need to  set the content to the activity first. If not your initialization fails leading to `NullPointerException`.

Also you have button in xml its already initialized in your `onCreate`. No need to add it to  `webview`.

```
mWebview.addView(buttonClick); // not required
```

Also you have webview height `fill_parent`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView 
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/playButton"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/playButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Pause" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Always post the stacktrace in case of a crash. useful info about the crash is logged.

Comment: Alright, I'll do so next time. The only issue I have now is when I do mWebview.loadUrl the button disappears.

Comment: @OstapHnatyuk edited my post. this happens because you have `fill_parent` for webview which take the full height. try the above edited post.

Comment: @OstapHnatyuk also make sure you don't open url in browser. your web content should be in webview. if its a browser you can't put a button there. you can check that if it opens in a browser you click back button it will navigate to your app screen.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
        Button buttonClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);

        mWebview  = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enables javascript


        System.out.println("Loading Webpage...");
        new tts().execute("");
        mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.aljazeera.com/news/americas/2013/07/20137113200544375.html");
    }
```

You have to load the xml file before looking for View that are defined inside it. That is the work of the `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout)` call.