# Few android webview helps required (eclipse)

Tags: android, webview

I need few helps in android. i'm new to android

1. how to add menu/options bar to android webview? so that, when i click a button, it directly goes to another website in the same webview.

what should i do so this happens?
2. when i click back button, it must go to history/ back of visited website instead of closing the app.

3. syntax for refreshing the page a user is on.
4. transparent icons or image on top of the page, so when clicked, goes forward and backward.

Comment: These all are different questions and you can easily find them if you google them one by one.

Comment: i cant get it easily. that is why am asking here.

Comment: negative votes again? and no comments so far why negative comments? A newbie doesn't know how to ask a quality question. So one should help him first before negative vote.
@akhil : I will help you out here. But do proper RnD before asking.

Comment: thanks a lot bro.  I maynot know to ask a quality question, but im newbie and im just asking what all i want to know thats it.

Comment: But your answers should show enough efforts from your side as well, this question indicates that you straight away need code, doesn't show your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

For point 1. For OptoinsBar, [Check here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html), For menu, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439085/android-how-to-create-option-menu)

For point 2. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400426/android-enable-back-button-in-webview)

For point 3. Refreshing a page only needs calling `wbView(Your_url_here);` again. Don't know what you mean from 'when user is on'.

For point 4. [Show a button over Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812675/having-problems-putting-button-over-webview). And on their onClick. call `wbView.goBack()` or `goForward()` method.

I just googled all your points one by one, and reached to this answer.

Comment: by when user is on..i meant.. on the website/page user is on... ie how to reload a page from a button?

Comment: it will be visible, and by calling 'loadURL();` you will reload. This is how I interpreted your question.

Comment: ok.. My app is almost over thanks to Darpan. I need assistance on two more things.

Comment: ok.. My app is almost over thanks to Darpan. I need assistance on two more things.   
1. The options menu is shown only when i click 'menu' button. i need to display menu on the top, so that i can open it with menu option and clicking on options icons(3 vertical dots on top bar) for phones with no menu bar..

2. i want to assign a webpage to those options in menu. how should i do? 

3. how do i use onClick option.?